# How could I discriminate the functions which have the same name when using gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am debugging a `C` program which uses `unixODBC`. The program calls `SQLPrepare` function. During the running, the program will use `dl_open` to open the database `ODBC` driver library, which also has a function called `SQLPrepare`. How do I discriminate them?

For example, if I want to disassemble `SQLPrepare`, it actually disassembles the function which program uses directly:

```
(gdb) disassemble SQLPrepare
Dump of assembler code for function SQLPrepare:
   0x00007ffff7d7dbab <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00007ffff7d7dbac <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00007ffff7d7dbaf <+4>:     push   %rbx
```

I try to use "`disassemble libverticaodbc.so:SQLPrepare`" command to disassemble the function in database `ODBC` driver library, but it can't work:

```
(gdb) disassemble libverticaodbc.so:SQLPrepare
No symbol "libverticaodbc" in current context.
```

How could i discriminate them? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could i discriminate them?

If both functions do not have debug info, discriminating should be easy:

```
(gdb) info function SQLPrepare
... two separate addresses should be listed
(gdb) disas <addr1>
(gdb) disas <addr2>
```

If one or both functions do have debug info, you may run into [this](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13590) GDB bug.